# grocery push notification doesn't work

Tags: ios

i'm trying send notification two days but still nothing.
I use grocery gem and nothing. In Xcode is everything good(Code signing and Provisioning profile)

My grocery code is:

```
pusher = Grocer.pusher(
    certificate: "#{Rails.root}/config/cert.pem",      # required
    passphrase:  "password",                       # optional
    gateway:     "gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com", # optional; See note below.
    port:        2195,                     # optional
    retries:     3                         # optional
)
notification = Grocer::Notification.new(
    device_token:      "aed06--------------e8",
    alert:             "Hello from Grocer!",
    badge:             3,
    category:          "a category",         # optional; used for custom notification actions
    sound:             "siren.aiff",         # optional
    expiry:            Time.now + 60*60,     # optional; 0 is default, meaning the message is not stored
    identifier:        8805,                 # optional; must be an integer
    content_available: true                  # optional; any truthy value will set 'content-available' to 1
)
pusher.push(notification)`
```

Code is: 160

Can you help me, please?

Comment: you might want to include more suitable and informative tags.

Comment: Pff, I turned off my phone and went to sleep slowly. I tried it once with a disconnected phone and it works.... I had connected phone in Xcode for all times and notification doesn't work... i am a jerk